# Catch Microsoft Office PowerPoint slide changed event from Java?

Tags: java, api, ms-office, powerpoint, slideshow

I've seen a lots of libraries to manipulate over Microsoft Office PowerPoint but none of them seems to have the ability I need.

How can I catch events from currently running presentation/slideshow (that is full screen)?

I need event: **SlideChangedEvent**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're automating PowerPoint via COM, there's no event to catch. It's not a message broadcast using PostMessage() or SendMessage(); it's part of the COM automation interface.